# WPF Binding to DataGrid Context from CellStyle

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I have a WPF DataGrid that is bound to an observable collection of RowObjects with a bunch of bindable properties. To fill out the data in my table, I added DataGridTextColumns which bind to the properties of the RowObjects. For example:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource={Binding RowCollection}>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col1" Binding={Binding Property1Name, Mode=OneTime} IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col2" Binding={Binding Property2Name, Mode=OneTime} IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col3" Binding={Binding Property3Name, Mode=OneTime} IsReadOnly="True" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Let's say Property3 is an integer. I want the cells in Column3 to highlight to red when they are negative, yellow when it's zero, and green when it's positive. my first thought was to bind a System.Windows.Media.Color to the CellStyle of the DataGridTextColumn, but that doesn't seem to work directly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy, but you can use **Converter** for each cell **Background**

Style for one cell:

```
<Style x:Key="Col1DataGridCell" TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource Col1Converter}}" />
</Style>
```

Converter for one cell:

```
public class Col1Converter : IValueConverter {

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        var result = (RowObject)value;

        Color color;
        if (result.Value < 0) {
            color = Colors.Red;
        }
        else if (result.Value == 0) {
            color = Colors.Yellow;
        }
        else {
            color = Colors.Green;
        }

        return new SolidColorBrush(color);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Using in DataGrid:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Col1" Style={StaticResource Col1DataGridCell} Binding={Binding Property1Name, Mode=OneTime} IsReadOnly="True" />
```

Comment: I've submited almost the same solution, 17 seconds late...You win this time

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use Style that would change color of cell with help of IValueConverter

Check this : [MSDN BLOG](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2011/03/03/wpf-databinding-datagrid-and-simple-conditional-higher-than-using-ivalueconverter.aspx) and experiment.

Best of luck.